# Separate text to variables in R

Tags: r, csv, separator, strsplit

I have in one column of the table this:

```
paragemcard-resp+insufcardioresp
dpco+pneumonia
posopperfulceragastrica+ards
pos op hematoma #rim direito expontanea
miopatiaduchenne-erb+insuf.resp
dpco+dhca+#femur
posde#subtroncantГ©ricaesqВЄ+complicepidural
dpco+asma
```

And i want to separate them like this:

```
paragemcard-resp                            insufcardioresp
dpco                                        pneumonia
posopperfulceragastrica                     ards
pos op hematoma #rim direito expontanea
miopatiaduchenne-erb                        insuf.resp
dpco                                        dhca                   #femur
posde#subtroncantГ©ricaesqВЄ                complicepidural
dpco                                        asma
```

But the problem is that they don't have the same length.
As you can see, in line 3, we have 2 variable and in line 6 we have 3.

And i want to create this string in the same column for further analysis.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried `strsplit()`?

Comment: This is nothing more than a CSV file where the separator is '+' character (instead of the usual ',' or tab or ';'). Just use `read.csv/read.table` like @AnanandaMahto says; even simpler than strsplit.

Comment: @smci, yes and no. One limitation of the direct `read.table` approach is in cases like this one, where the data are unbalanced and where the row with the maximum number of fields is not within the first five rows.

Comment: Ah. Can you not kludge by prepending a header or dummy line 1 using the maximum number of variables? e.g. `var1+var2+var3...` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `read.table`, but you should use `count.fields` or some kind of regex to figure out the correct number of columns first. Using Robert's "text" sample data:

```
Cols <- max(sapply(gregexpr("+", text, fixed = TRUE), length))+1
## Cols <- max(count.fields(textConnection(text), sep = "+"))

read.table(text = text, comment.char="", header = FALSE, 
           col.names=paste0("V", sequence(Cols)), 
           fill = TRUE, sep = "+")
#                                        V1              V2     V3
# 1                        paragemcard-resp insufcardioresp       
# 2                                    dpco       pneumonia       
# 3                 posopperfulceragastrica            ards       
# 4 pos op hematoma #rim direito expontanea                       
# 5                    miopatiaduchenne-erb      insuf.resp       
# 6                                    dpco            dhca #femur
# 7            posde#subtroncantГ©ricaesqВЄ complicepidural       
# 8                                    dpco            asma
```

Also, possibly useful: the "stringi" library makes counting elements easy (as an alternative to the `gregexpr` step above).

```
library(stringi)
Cols <- max(stri_count_fixed(x, "+") + 1)
```

---

Why the need for the "Cols" step? `read.table` and family decides how many columns to use either by (1) the maximum number of fields detected within the first 5 rows of data or (2) the length of the `col.names` argument. In your example row with the most number of fields is the sixth row, so directly using `read.csv` or `read.table` would result in incorrectly wrapped data.

Comment: Can you not kludge by prepending a header or dummy line 1 using the maximum number of variables? e.g. `var1+var2+var3...` ?

Comment: @smci, sure... if you know how many variables you will need in the first place. With ragged data like this, it can be quite frustrating to think that you have read the data in correctly only to view the last few lines and find things totally out of whack because somewhere in the file were a few rows with more values than others.

Comment: Trivial: you either use awk to find the line with the maximal count of '+'. Or `egrep '(.*\+){5}(.*)'` where we manually step the number 5 down from say 9. Not everything has to be programmatic if this is a quick hack.

Comment: @smci, not necessarily trivial if someone can't recognize that they are just dealing with a csv in disguise ;-)

Comment: Yes, that's why we're helping OP... ;-) R's "CSV file" is a severe misnomer, it should really be called "delimited record format", becos that it what it is. Also, the separator should be a regex, to allow multiple separators e.g. '[,;\t]'. I can feel a more general `read.records(...)` coming on, where sep can be a regex... any other generalizations needed? perhaps hint at and infer colClasses? and why in general do we not estimate nrows with a simple `wc -l` on the file? all for the sake of time- and memory-efficiency. And for f***'s sake, do an optional `gc(reset=TRUE)` afterwards.

Comment: @smci, multiple separators would be awesome.... I think the "gsubfn" package has (or is planning to have) something that lets you read data in with a pattern to specify columns. I have no idea of its efficiency in comparison to something like awk though.

Comment: Because `data.table::fread()` got implemented to improve the basic efficiency of `read.csv`/reading formatted files... sadly people are reinventing pluralities of wheels... it's like a Douglas Adams parody... :(

Comment: @smci, `fread` can only handle rectangular data. Ragged data like this won't work out of the box unless the correct number of delimiters are added to each line to make each row have the same number of delimiters.

Comment: I know that, Ananda. I said it got implemented to improve the basic efficiency of the common-case of read.csv (known, fixed number of both columns and rows). And neglects ragged cases like this. Also no read-command handles a separator regex. We need a more general and more performant `read.records()` or `read.csv3()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `strsplit`:

```
text <- c("paragemcard-resp+insufcardioresp", "dpco+pneumonia", "posopperfulceragastrica+ards", "pos op hematoma #rim direito expontanea", "miopatiaduchenne-erb+insuf.resp", "dpco+dhca+#femur", "posde#subtroncantГ©ricaesqВЄ+complicepidural", "dpco+asma")

strings <- strsplit(text, "+", fixed = TRUE)
maxlen <- max(sapply(strings, length))
strings <- lapply(strings, function(s) { length(s) <- maxlen; s })
strings <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(strings), ncol = maxlen, byrow = TRUE))
```

and it looks like

```
                                          X1              X2     X3
   1                        paragemcard-resp insufcardioresp   <NA>
   2                                    dpco       pneumonia   <NA>
   3                 posopperfulceragastrica            ards   <NA>
   4 pos op hematoma #rim direito expontanea            <NA>   <NA>
   5                    miopatiaduchenne-erb      insuf.resp   <NA>
   6                                    dpco            dhca #femur
   7            posde#subtroncantГ©ricaesqВЄ complicepidural   <NA>
   8                                    dpco            asma   <NA>
```